# Using base default constructor (with parameters) for child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class A which has to have a a class passed to it; From A I have two classes  B and C; is it possible for B and C to use the constructor from A, as apposed to the default constructor.

```
     A
    / \
   B   C 

A::A(randomNumber &rnd)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(randomNumber& rnd) : A(rnd) { }
    // ...
};
```

If you want to call `A`'s constructor in `B`'s default constructor, you will have to pass a global object: since `A`'s construct accepts an lvalue reference, creating a temporary is not an option.

```
B() : A(global_random_number);
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. For anyone looking at this answer
You should not include type names in function calls... it confuses the compiler. Something I had to work out :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use

```
class B {
public:
   B() : A(someRndNum) {}
};
```

and same for C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax:

```
B::B() : A(aRandomNum)
{
    ....
}
```