# Default constructor parameters in inheritant class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, default

I need to use default parameters for an inherited class's constructor.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int data)
    {
        a_data = data;
    }
    ~A(){}

    int a_data; 
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int in, int num = DATA) : A(num)
    {
        b_data = in;
    }
    const int DATA = 9;
    int b_data;
};

int main()
{
    B b(3);
    int x = b.a_data;

    return 0;
}
```

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569020/using-base-default-constructor-with-parameters-for-child-class) that I can use a default parameters for a child's class constructor. But it is said that we should use a global parameter.

But I use a data from class "B" so the A constructor is called before this data is released. In the result I get some garbage in "x" but not 9.

! So, the problem was extracted from another, more particular one. I have a  basic class "Object". And some children like "Mob" or "Player". Object has a physical (Box2D) object inside. Certanly, all the actions creating that physical body are the same, except of some parametres. So, I store algorythm in "Object" construtor, and put all the needed data in child classes. But, I can't reach this data, before creating an "Object" which requires that data.

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) is an example of the solution for one dependent class.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could someone explain why the version above still compiles, but does not produce 9? Does the compiler just ignore `cost int num = 9` when constructing A?

Comment: @rivanov the compiler first constructs the Base part of a Derived object, and only after it initializes the other members of the Derived object. When it tries to construct the Base, the members of the Derived object are not yet initialized.

Comment: @vsoftco Ah I see, so what you're saying is, when `B(int in) : A(num)` is called, this is executed before `const int num = 9`, which is 0 by default. Thus `A(num)` is always called with 0. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @vsoftco, [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member)  is an example of solution, but as I understand it wouldn't work for a structure with muiltiple children classes?

Comment: @rivanov the `num` is not even `0`, it is uninitialized. It happens to be zero in some cases, but in general trying to use un-initialized variables is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Entrack thanks for the link, I am not sure, will take a look.

Comment: @vsoftco, oh it's R_Kapp's link :)

Comment: @vsoftco, I updated the description, it might help. Certanly, I can redo structure, even if I should waste a lot of time on it, but it still interesting how to solve this recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value constructor such as:

```
B(int in, int num = 9) : A(num) {
    b_data = in;
}
```

This works as shown [here](http://ideone.com/gs03oN).

Comment: I already tried this variant, but I get an error: "a non static member must be relative to a specific object"

Comment: @vsoftco: Thank you for your comment; means something from a >10k user such as yourself.

Comment: @Entrack: I've literally copy pasted your code and made that change; it compiles and works as shown in the link. If there is an error, it is because of something else in your code that is different than what is shown in the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean if you put this into the constructor you get an error
    B(int in, int num = num) : A(num)
    {
        b_data = in;
    }

Comment: @Entrack: Ah, no that's not going to work, you have to put an actual value there `int num = 9` should work if that's the default value you want to construct it with. Otherwise, use a different value and ignore the `const int` variable altogether.

Comment: @R_Kapp then I'll have another problem. You see, I'm making a game, and there is an entity "Object" which has many chilren like "Player" or "Mob". Object creates a physical body in Box2D and it's constructor takes some parameters. So I want to put required data in "Mob" class, which can be inserted, while constructing Object::Mob. 
It will give an opportunity to create a Mob only by: Mob(x_coord, y_coord), but not the whole list of physical data.

Comment: @Entrack, I haven't read enough to know whether it's really the right solution for you, but you can [introduce a base class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) to force the member to be initialized first.

Comment: @R_Kapp, anyway it won't save me from the problem. I have an "Object". It needs individual parameters for each child class. If I store required data in chilren, I won't be able to get it, before Object constructs. ////////////////// The solution on wikibooks (as I understand) can't provide various parameters for each children class. But I hope I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to provide a default constructor for `A`

```
A(int data = 9)
```

so `B` can create by default `A`s that have `9` as their parameter,

```
B(int in){...} // here the A part is constructed with 9
```

Your actual code doesn't do what you expect since the constructor of `B` first tries to construct the base part (in this case `A`), and only after initialized the rest of `B`.

Comment: Basicly, no. I need 2 parametres to create B.
"in" and "num" -- default one

Comment: @Entrack See the updated edit. Otherwise, you'd need a global variable, which is not the way to go.

Comment: You see, if I have more child classes whith individual parametres, it would be incorrect

Comment: @Entrack see the R_Kapp's answer, as I think it's better than mine and I think does exactly what you want. If it's still not satisfactory, maybe you should think about changing the design ;)